# how can i get the values in srcs similar to the example shared bellow?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, request, html-parsing

My code to get all the links in the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
r  = requests.get("http://site-to.crawl")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

However i do want for example the content of both srcs as in :

```
"mov_bbb.mp4" and `"mov_bbb.ogg"`


<video id="video1" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" controls="">
        <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      </video>
```

how can i achieve that not just for this example but for all videos video tags later where i would get the src.

another example:

```
<video controls="" src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4" poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/title_anouncement.jpg?x11217" width="620">

</video>
```

what i want here https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4

i'd want the code to work for both sample examples and basically similar ones, when there is tags video i want the src, it might be directly in the same <> or in its sub

Answer (score 0):

You can get the  tags in the parsed html. Then just get the src's of those tags.

Give this a try:

```
 for i in range(len(soup.find_all('source'))):
     print(soup.find_all('source')[i]['src'])
```

***Edit

So we can first check if the  has a src attribute. if it does not it will check child  tags and print their src.

```
for video in soup.find_all('video',attrs={'src':True}):
    print(video['src'])
for video in soup.find_all('video',attrs={'src':False}):
    for i in video.find_all('source'):
        print(i['src'])
```

Comment: No i rather work another way, when it finds a tag video i want it to look further in the subs

Comment: Kindly check the edit i'd want the code to work for both sample examples and basically similar ones, when there is tags video i want the src, it might be directly in the same <> or in its sub

Comment: Error soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elias/Desktop/scrap_test/test.py", line 124, in <module>
    if videoTag['src'] != None:
  File "/home/user/Desktop/scrap_test/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1071, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'src'

Comment: Doesn't work, i gave examples kindly check the code on them before posting an answer.

Comment: There is a video on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video it's the second example i shared in my question and it didn't work on it

Comment: That is because there is no video element in the soup. That website might be loading their video content via javascript. That means you can not request it with requests.get(). You should use an actual browser to get the java scripted content. Take a look at selenium.

Comment: I printed soup and it seems to be fine

Comment: Search soup for "<video" there is none or just do soup.find('video') it returns as none.